# How to add new data to all exiting documents in monogdb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add isFavorite:false in all documents but i couldnot do it

[image]

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{$set: {"isFavorite":false}});
```

Comment: Shouldn't also make sure his schema has `isFavorite` as well ?